# How to have content shared to facebook via my web app show as "via [my app name]"?

Tags: facebook

How do I create a facebook share link in my web app so that it will display as "via [my app name]" in the timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All posts/links/photos/etc made via your app will be attributed to it in the frontend;

If you *don't* get a 'via' link i'd be very surprised and it could indicate you're not doing things correctly (e.g using sharer.php or a like button instead of a feed dialog)

Comment: I assume I need some very basic reading, right now I'm using a very basic share button using the http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php URL. I assume I need then to do it via the API/SDK? there is no "URL only" API?

Comment: No, if you use that URL it's not attributed to your app; you'd need to use something like the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) with the Javascript SDK to have the link be posted from your app